# Java error: package 'x' does not exist

Tags: java, file, directory, javac, java-package

So I have a file tree in Linux that looks like this:

- ~/keyboard_warriors/

  - test/

    - ConfigTest.java
  - ConfigParser.class
  - ConfigParser.java

The problem is that when I try to type in Terminal:
    `javac ConfigTest.java`

I get the error:

```
ConfigTest.java:2: error: package keyboard_warriors does not exist  
import keyboard_warriors.*;  
^
```

This is really bugging me and I could not find any answers anywhere. If you could solve my problem, I would be a very happy person.

Comment: That's not a package, that's your root directory... I'd suggest using an IDE.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/packages.html

Comment: Hey guys, I found the answer. While in the ~ directory, I did `javac -cp "." keyboard_warriors/test/ConfigTest.java`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer a long time ago but forgot to post it. sorry :). It is actually quite simple. I was trying to compile the classes from inside the `test/` folder. What I did was go up to where all the classes were accessible without having to use a absolute path and without using `../` in the path (AKA the `keyboard_warriors/` folder. I just compile from there and everything was A-OK. Thanks for the input though, it did help some ;).

Answer (score 0):

It's not going to recognize a directory outside of the classpath as being part of the classpath.

What you probably want is to include another folder inside of where your test is being run:

```
test/
    keyboard_warriors/
        ConfigTest.java
        ConfigParser.java
```

This also presumes that you have declared these classes to be in the `keyboard_warriors` classpath, by this:

```
package keyboard_warriors;
```

Depending on how you're compiling these classes, you'd have to add it to the classpath with the `-cp` flag on `javac`.

Comment: Perhaps, but from the structure quoted, just adjusting the classpath is not likely to be the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Given the structure you've quoted, it would be odd to be importing `keyboard_warriors` into `ConfigTest`; from the structure, you'd expect to see `package keyboard_warriors;` instead, because `ConfigTest` is in the `keyboard_warriors` directory.

If `ConfigTest` *isn't* in the `keyboard_warriors` package, it's probably in the wrong directory.

In general: When you're compiling classes, the `.java` file should be in a directory named for the package it's in. So for instance, if `ConfigTest` is meant to be in the package, you'd keep your directory/file structure as it is and use

```
package keyboard_warriors;
```

...in `ConfigTest.java`.

If `ConfigTest` *isn't* meant to be in that package, you'd probably move it out of that directory; perhaps:

- ~/keyboard_warriors/

  - test/

    - ConfigTest.java
- ConfigParser.class
- ConfigParser.java

...and then `import keyboard_warriors.*;` would make sense, provided that your home directory is in your classpath.